# Progress dialog dont appear after a listview click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i load a listview with an asynctask and i show the progressdialog correctly.

But when i click in a listview item, i go to other activity to load the item details, but the progress dialog dont appear in the second activity. I use the same code in both.
Can i have problems if i use the progress dialog after a listview click?

I go to the second activity with this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(Context, Class);
```

startActivity(intent);

And i make the asynctask with this code

```
private class CargarVacas extends AsyncTask<String, Float, Integer>{
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Class);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Cargando..."); 
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return 250;
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(Integer bytes) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
     }
}
```

The progressdialog only appear less than one second although i use a 10 seconds Thread sleep

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: Where is the sleep ?

Comment: I dont added here, but i used only for test.

Comment: Post it anyway please

Comment: try {
  Thread.sleep(5000);         
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
I use this, but the activity is bloqued during 5 seconds and later appear without the progress dialog

Comment: The sleep is in doInBackground ? I think you should post more of your code.

Comment: Yes, i think that i solved. I use .get() in the asynctask and i think that this is the problem. I will test and i will comment the result